# What are these chars?

Tags: html, character-encoding, textfield

How is possible to do this ʘͥͥͥͥͥͥͥͥͥͥͥͥͥͥ͒_ʘͥͥͥͥͥͥͥͥͥͥͥͥͥͥ͒ in a html input field?

Or this:

ه҉̿҉̿҉̿҉̿҉̿҉̿҉̿҉̿҉̿҉̿҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉      ه҉̿҉̿҉̿҉̿҉̿҉̿҉̿҉̿҉̿҉̿҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉҉

I just copied and pasted from a Twitter profile. I guess that they are pasting unicode chars in hex but looking at http://www.htmlescape.net/unicode_charts.html I couldn't find any char that overflow vertically or left.

I'm asking because I want to know how this can be avoided. It's possible that people start to use this and break the look and style of many commentable sites, just like I did. Sorry...

Comment: May be it's duplicated but it's something very difficult to search for. Anyway, I think that the answer bellow by raina77ow is much better and complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's so called [**Combining Diacritical Marks**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks_%28Unicode_block%29). The code in the question, in particular, uses [**U+0365 COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER I**](http://codepoints.net/U+0365) character. You can easily create yourself something very similar right in the browser, using this code:

```
var iMark = String.fromCharCode(869); // 0x365 in decimal
var testString = 'f' + Array(11).join(iMark); // f with 10 dots above
```

This behaviour (combining all these marks instead of using just a single one) is well described in the [**official FAQ**](http://www.unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html):

> **Q:** Unicode doesn't contain the character I need, which is a Latin
>   letter with a certain diacritical mark. Can you add it?
>
> **A:** Unicode can already express almost anything you will ever need in
>   any field of study by using a combination of Latin, IPA, or other base
>   letters with the various combining diacritical marks. For example, if
>   you need a highly specialized character such as “Z with stroke,
>   cedilla, and umlaut”, you can get this combination by using three
>   existing character codes in combination:
>
> ```
>  U+01B5 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z WITH STROKE
>  U+0327 COMBINING CEDILLA
>  U+0308 COMBINING DIAERESIS
> ```
>
> With appropriate rendering software, that sequence should produce a
>   glyph combination like this:
>   [image]
>
> Even if the combination is not available in a particular font, it is
>   unambiguous and Unicode conformant systems should transmit and retain
>   the sequence without distortion, and it may be processed
>   programmatically.

How to deal with this (potential) nastiness without affecting the valid texts? One possible approach, I suppose, is normalizing ([**NFC**](http://www.macchiato.com/unicode/nfc-faq)) the strings first, then stripping away all the non-valid characters.

Comment: related: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) rather worrisome example of what it *may* lead to. (Not right before going to sleep.)